# Find the intersection of two linked lists but my code returns null?

Tags: java, algorithm

I was working on a problem to find the intersection of two linked lists and my solution passed all the test cases on LeetCode. However, when I tested using the same test case on my own IDE (IntelliJ), I was told "Cannot read field 'val' because 'test' is null". Much appreciated if someone can point out what I miss here!

```
class ListNode {

  int val;
  ListNode next;

  ListNode () {}

  ListNode (int val) {
    this.val = val;
  }

  ListNode (int val, ListNode next) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

public class Q160 {
  public static ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB) {

    int sizeA = getSize(headA);
    int sizeB= getSize(headB);

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(sizeA - sizeB); i++) {
      if (sizeA > sizeB) {
        headA = headA.next;
      }
      else {
        headB = headB.next;
      }
    }

    while (headA != null && headB != null) {
      if (headA == headB) {
        return headA;
      }
      headA = headA.next;
      headB = headB.next;
    }

    return null;
  }

  private static int getSize(ListNode head) {
    int count = 0;

    while (head != null) {
      count++;
      head = head.next;
    }

    return count;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListNode hA = new ListNode(4, new ListNode(1, new ListNode(8, new ListNode(4, new ListNode(5)))));
    ListNode hB = new ListNode(5, new ListNode(6, new ListNode(1, new ListNode(8, new ListNode(4, new ListNode(5))))));

    ListNode test = getIntersectionNode(hA, hB);
    System.out.println(test.val);
  }
}
```

Comment: `getIntersectionNode` always returns null..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (headA == headB) {
    return headA;
}
```

For your test cases this will always return false. The reason for this is that Java uses the `==` operator for reference comparison. `hA` and `hB` contain entirely different objects.

Probably what you would want to do is to use the `val` member for checking the equality, which will result in something like this:

```
if (headA.val == headB.val) {
    return headA;
}
```

This will work, because `val` is a primitive `int` and it will compared as expected.

Comment: Or implement `equals()` and use that.